# How to avoid object copy at vector list initialization and how to extend the lifetime of a temporary

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

Consider the code bellow where a number of objects from class "MyType" are stored inside a vector, then this vector are passed to an object of class "VectorProcessor":

```
// to compile, run: g++ -Wall --std=c++17 test.cpp -o test
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyType {
private:
    int x;
public:
    MyType(int a_x) {
        this->x = a_x;
        cout << "MyType constructor; x=" << this->x << endl;
    }
    ~MyType() {
        cout << "MyType destructor; x=" << this->x << endl;
        this->x = 0;
    }
    MyType(const MyType &o)  {
        this->x = o.x +10;
        cout << "MyType copy constructor; x=x'+10=" << this->x << endl;
    }
    MyType& operator=(const MyType& o)  {
        this->x = o.x +20;
        cout << "MyType =copy constructor; x=x'+20=" << this->x << endl;
        return *this;
    }
    MyType(MyType &&o) {
        this->x = o.x + 30;
        cout << "MyType move constructor; x=x'+30=" << this->x << endl;
    }
    MyType & operator=(MyType &&o) {
        this->x = o.x + 40;
        cout << "MyType =move constructor; x=x'+40=" << this->x << endl;
        return *this;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const MyType& s) {
        return os << s.x;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class VectorProcessor {
    private:
        const vector<T> &v;
    public:
        VectorProcessor(const vector<T> &a_lista): v{a_lista} {
            cout << "VectorProcessor constructor" << endl;
        }
        VectorProcessor(const vector<T> &&a_lista): v(a_lista) {
            cout << "VectorProcessor rvalue constructor" << endl;
        }
        const T& getLast() {
            return this->v[this->v.size()-1];
        }
};

int main() {
#if 1
    // test (A)
    vector<MyType> v{1,2,3,4,5};
    VectorProcessor<MyType> r(v);
#else
    // test (B)
    VectorProcessor<MyType> r(vector<MyType>{1,2,3,4,5});
#endif
    cout << "r.getLast(): " << r.getLast() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If I enable "test A", the program output is:

```
MyType constructor; x=1
MyType constructor; x=2
MyType constructor; x=3
MyType constructor; x=4
MyType constructor; x=5
MyType copy constructor; x=x'+10=11
MyType copy constructor; x=x'+10=12
MyType copy constructor; x=x'+10=13
MyType copy constructor; x=x'+10=14
MyType copy constructor; x=x'+10=15
MyType destructor; x=5
MyType destructor; x=4
MyType destructor; x=3
MyType destructor; x=2
MyType destructor; x=1
VectorProcessor constructor
r.getLast(): 15
MyType destructor; x=11
MyType destructor; x=12
MyType destructor; x=13
MyType destructor; x=14
MyType destructor; x=15
```

And If I enable "test B", the program output is:

```
MyType constructor; x=1
MyType constructor; x=2
MyType constructor; x=3
MyType constructor; x=4
MyType constructor; x=5
MyType copy constructor; x=x'+10=11
MyType copy constructor; x=x'+10=12
MyType copy constructor; x=x'+10=13
MyType copy constructor; x=x'+10=14
MyType copy constructor; x=x'+10=15
VectorProcessor rvalue constructor
MyType destructor; x=11
MyType destructor; x=12
MyType destructor; x=13
MyType destructor; x=14
MyType destructor; x=15
MyType destructor; x=5
MyType destructor; x=4
MyType destructor; x=3
MyType destructor; x=2
MyType destructor; x=1
r.getLast(): 0
```

Then I ask: Without using pointers, or smart pointers,

1) How to avoid extra copying that occours in the objects from MyType class (for both test A and B)?
2) In the "test B", why the MyType destructor are called before r.getLast()? In other words, how to extent the lifetime of the temporary `vector<MyType>{1,2,3,4,5}` to the end of block?

Comment: where you wrote `=copy constructor`, that is actually the copy assignment operator (which is not a constructor).  Similar for the move assignment operator

Comment: From a more opiniated POV: If it wasn't for you intentionally injecting side-effects in the various constructors, the compiler would very likely be able to optimize away whatever cost you incur from invoking the move constructor an extra time, so the distinction is likely to not matter nearly as much as you expect it to.

Comment: This question is a little backward - a more relevant question is often how to avoid creating temporaries (or allow/force the compiler to elide them). Generally speaking, an unnamed temporary created within a statement (e.g. in your case B, the object used to construct `r`) exists only until the end of the statement. Depending on context, one way to extend life of an temporary is to give it a name (e.g. initialise a `const` reference to refer to it) so the object lasts while the reference is in scope. But the life on an unnamed temporary cannot be extended until the end of the enclosing scope

Answer (score 0):

The way `std::initializer_list` was designed, the initializer is equivalent to:

```
vector<MyType> v{ MyType(1), MyType(2), MyType(3), MyType(4), MyType(5) };
```

i.e. it creates temporary `MyType`s to construct the initializer list, and then the vector constructor copies its elements from the initializer list.  Some people regard this as a mistake but we are stuck with it now.

To avoid the extra objects you can construct elements in-place, e.g.:

```
vector<MyType> v;
v.reserve(5);
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i)
    v.emplace_back(i);
```

There are various ways this code can be wrapped, but this is the basic idea.

---

For your second question, temporary objects only live until the end of the full-expression in which they were created, except for a few exceptional cases.  Binding to a constructor reference parameter is not one of the exceptions.  The code you have in `test (A)` is the correct way to do this.

Comment: _"Binding to a constructor reference parameter is not one of the exceptions"_: May you explain it a bit more? What are the exceptions (how to extend the lifetime of a temporary?

Comment: @Berk7871 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary